# nmap on local host shows "filtered" on port which is stated as "open" on remote host

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, nmap

My question is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264832/server-ufw-port-is-open-but-remote-nmap-returns-filtered) *but I'd like to fix and understand the error without having to rely on the possibility that factory-resetting my router will fix it for me.* I also found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313906/cannot-open-port-on-ubuntu) which is about the same problem but left unanswered. There seems to be a hidden issue others and me must be missing.

I want to reach an ubuntu 20.04 server with my local zorin 16 machine. The server is hosting a minecraft server (this is irrelevant to this question, it only explains why i need port `25565`) within my LAN. I ran

```
$ sudo ufw allow 25565/tcp
```

on both of them. Checking

```
$ nmap localhost -p 25565
```

on the server reveals that the port is open, while calling the server from the main machine with

```
$ nmap 192.168.x.xxx -p 25565
```

just shows `filtered`. Both firewalls are active and allow tcp traffic through port `25565`. From my limited understanding, nothing seems wrong, yet here i am not being able to connect to the server. What could be wrong?

*Edit*: Also, when looking at `ufw status` it looks like the configuration for a working port like `22` is set up the exact same way as `25565`. Could it be that another app like `iptables` is messing with my config behind the scenes?

*Edit*: Running the server with or without `sudo` does not change anything.

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu being used?

Comment: @David 20.04 Focal Fossa